# Слияние похожих цветов

Tags: php

Необходимо уменьшить кол-во оттенков разных цветов. Пытался для этого использовать [imagetruecolortopalette()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagetruecolortopalette.php) из библиотеки GD, но ее поведение в слиянии цветов часто не очевидны. Если к примеру выбрать 8 цветов, то она может оставить несколько оттенков розового, но при этом слить красный и синий в один.

Возможно есть какие-то альтернативы?

Answer (score 1):

Есть вариант уменьшить до 16х16, получив, таким образом, 256 усредненных цветов, потом уже применив эту функцию. Если на картинке присутствуют мелкие разноцветные детали, придется с ними разобраться вручную.